# Elasticsearch Phrase Match In Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, phrase

I have a query that searches given terms in a text field by given time interval. I want to add phrase match to this query how can I add; for example I'll look for "has parti" as a phrase but the text shouldn't have "ahmet" word. How can I do this; the code is here;

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "text": [
                  "has",
                  "parti"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gt": "2015-08-27",
                  "lte": "2015-08-28"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elasticsearch provides [Phrase matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html), but I don't think you can use it in the [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html), or at least I didn't manage to have it working. I have a solution, with `match_phrase` in the `query`, together with the condition that `text` does not contain `ahmet`, while the time interval stays in the `filter`. Check if it's good enough for you.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "text": "has parti"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "text": "ahmet"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "date": {
                                    "gt": "2015-08-27",
                                    "lte": "2015-08-28"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the Way, your `date` looks like being mapped as string, because otherwise  your request would fail with

> ElasticsearchParseException[failed to parse date field [2015-08-22], tried both date format [date_time], and timestamp number]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"2015-08-22\" is too short]; }]

I suggest using a proper mapping, but that's not really related to your question

UPDATE:

Just came back to add that [we did the right thing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html): filters are not for *full-text* search

UPDATE:

Since [the **filtered** query has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-execution-coming-elasticsearch-2-0), in new versions the query should be rewritten in order to move the filter inside the **bool** query:

```
{

    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match_phrase": {
                    "text": "has parti"
                }
            }],
            "must_not": [{
                "match": {
                    "text": "ahmet"
                }
            }],
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "range": {
                            "date": {
                                "gt": "2015-08-27",
                                "lte": "2015-08-28"
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [phrase match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html).
But then as this is a query and as you are looking for a filter , you need to wrap this in [query filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html).

Once this is done , you should be able to implement phrase match filter.
Next as you need a negation , put your statement inside must_not of the bool filter. You can use term filter for the same.

So finally your query should look something like this -

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "title": "ahmet"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gt": "2015-08-27",
                  "lte": "2015-08-28"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "constantScore": {
                "filter": {
                  "query": {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "title": "has parti"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this fail with QueryParsingException?

Comment: nested: QueryParsingException[[<index_name>] No filter registered for [constantScore]]